# ArrayList in java, only doing an action once

Tags: java, arraylist

For some reason, I'm drawing a blank on this one. I have an ArrayList that contains CDs (some of them identical in name) and I want to print a String that tells how many I have of each CD.  For example, a string that says "You have: (1) AlbumOne, (2) AlbumTwo, (1) AlbumThree" etc. The CDs are not sorted. How can I do this?

Comment: And you can't just sort the array? You could also just run through the list and build a `Map` of the CD title and count, then just output how many you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java arraylist format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089385/java-arraylist-format)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to loop thru the array, and use a map that uses the objects as keys and the values as counts.  So

```
Map<YourObject, Integer> counter ...
```

As you loop thru the array, do a `get` on the counter for the current object in the array.  If you get null, initialize the value at that bucket in the map to be 1.  If you have a value, increment it.  Then you can loop over the map to get your readout.

Note that if you use a `Hashmap`, your objects have to implement the `hashcode` and `equals` method properly.  You don't have to use your object, if it has keys or some other distinguishing field, the keys in your map can be that...

Comment: It would probably work better if the map were indexed by the CD name.

Comment: @ted, yeah i added another paragraph.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to override hashcode and equals - it partially depends on how you've implemented the class. It's a good idea to do it, but not necessary depending on the circumstances.

Comment: right, what i said was they have to implement them properly.  If that is already done, then yay.

Comment: OP here. I'm confused about this hashmap stuff. If I wanted to do it by name, should I change Integer to String?

Comment: you would change `YourObject` to String

Answer (score 1):

```
//aggregate details
Map<String, Integer> albumCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String album : albums) {
    Integer count = albumCounts.get(album); 
    if (count == null) {
        count = 0;
    }
    albumCounts.put(album, count + 1);
}

//print stats
System.out.println("You have:");
for (String album : albums) {
   System.out.println("(" + albumCounts.get(album) + ") " + album);
}
```

Comment: OP here. I'm confused about this hashmap stuff. If I wanted to do it by name, should I change Integer to String?

Comment: If you are using the 'name' as index, the 'get' operation will return you the stored number for that index. So it would apply to your problem.

Comment: When I try to implement this I get the album names and their appropriate quantities, but I also get duplicate names: "(3) AlbumOne, (2) AlbumTwo, (3) AlbumOne [THIS IS WRONG]" etc.

Comment: @dylandrop - If you are using a custom `Album` class and not just a list of strings for your album list, then you will need to follow hvgotcodes's advice about implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused about the `Map`. Use of `Map` *is* appropriate to solve such a problem (as you have posted) So please visit [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) link (tutorial) and read/learn about Map.